# How can I control a Mac's keyboard with an iOS device via bluetooth?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, bluetooth, keyboard

I'm trying to make an iOS application where you can control a mac's keyboard via bluetooth.

What I want is to pair an iPhone/iPod/iPad and a Mac's keyboard and then, send to the Mac's keyboard  the key I want to press from the iOS device. I have searched but the answers and tutorials always shows examples about other devices (like health care devices or arduinos) and connection between iOS devices. Is there anybody who knows how to do what I need? I appreciate your answers. Thanks for reading me!

Comment: I've been looking to understand this same thing. Please answer your own question if you've found out how to do it. Thanks.